# Does anyone know to make this a single line statement? (python)

Tags: python, if-statement

```
 if min_value <= value <= max_value:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: yes you can. There is no need to ask, you could test it yourselves.

Comment: yes.  what have you tried?

Comment: This is already answered. Google: [python compact if then else](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+compact+if+then+else)

Comment: >>> True if 1 <= 2 <= 3 else False

Answer (score 1):

Since a conditional expression evaluates to `True` or `False`, just return the conditional value.

```
def isBetween(min_value, max_value, value):
    return min_value <= value <= max_value

print isBetween(1, 10, 5)
```

This prints `True`.

Comment: i inputted that into python but it results in an error

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  Python Shell, prompt 1, line 1
builtins.NameError: name 'is_between' is not defined

Comment: You don't get the same error when you use the original `if` statement? What is `value` set to?

Comment: nope when i evaluated with the if statement that i had posted, it worked fine. there was no error. value is suppose to be  between min and max value or equal to one or both of them

Comment: it resulted in an error:( i'm a new programmer and I'm honestly so frustrated. I'm suppose to condense the body of this function into one line.import math

EMPTY = '-'

def is_between(value, min_value, max_value):
    """ (number, number, number) -> bool

    Precondition: min_value <= max_value

    Return True if and only if value is between min_value and max_value,
    or equal to one or both of them.

    >>> is_between(1.0, 0.0, 2)
    True
    >>> is_between(0, 1, 2)
    False
    """
    if min_value <= value <= max_value:
        return True
    else:
        return False

Comment: I can't tell what you're doing there, since there's no formatting in comments. Edit your question to show what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this
`return True if min_value <= value <= max_value else False` inside your function or method.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it is this:

```
>>> min_value = 1
>>> max_value = 10
>>> value = 5
>>> print(min_value <= value <= max_value)
True
>>> value = 11
>>> print(min_value <= value <= max_value)
False
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually can. 
Try

```
def checkValue(min, max, value):
    return True if min <= value <= max else False
```

You can also do.

```
 def checkVlaue(min, max, value):
        true = True if min <= value <= max
        false = False if min >= value >= max
        return True if true and not false else False if false is not False and True is False else False
```